# Julia v0.6 constructors and 'new' keyword

Tags: types, julia

I'm quite confused by parametric composite types (structs) in Julia. I'm using v0.6. I wonder if anyone can explain to me the difference between these two bits of code? The first one seems to work but the second gives errors (`ERROR: LoadError: syntax: too few type parameters specified in "new{...}"`). I am specifically confused re:

- What is e.g. `Point{G}(x,y) where {G<:Integer} = new(55,y)` inside the first Point definition. It doesn't seem to be a method? See `println(methods(Point))` a couple of lines later. Is it a 'constructor'? If so what then is the difference between a  constructor and a method?
- What does the keyword `new` really do?
- Why is the second chunk of code not valid?

`

```
workspace()
println("\nSTART")

struct Point{T<:Real}
    x::T
    y::T
    # These are not 'methods' - see below. What are they!?
    Point{G}(x,y) where {G<:Integer} = new(55,y)
    Point{H}(x,y) where {H<:AbstractFloat} = new(x, 11)
end
println(methods(Point)) # Interesting!!!

# Are these methods? Are they 'constructors'?
Point(x::T, y::T) where {T<:Integer} = Point{T}(x,y)
Point(x::T, y::T) where {T<:AbstractFloat} = Point{T}(x,y)
println(methods(Point))

p = Point(2,3)
p2 = Point(2.0,3.0)

##########################################################################

# Errors!
workspace()
println("")

struct Point{T<:Real}
    x::T
    y::T
    Point(x::T, y::T) where {T<:Integer} = new(55, y)
    Point(x::T, y::T) where {T<:AbstractFloat} = new(x, 11)
end
println(methods(Point))

p = Point(2,3)
p2 = Point(2.0,3.0)
```

`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should read [this part of the Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/constructors/).

Short answers to your questions:

1) A method does any kind of thing. A constructor creates an object. (It is a special method if you will)

2) It is used to create an object within a type definition.

3) Use `new{T}(55,y)` instead of `new(55,y)`.

**First case**

Your `Point{G}(x,y) where {G<:Integer} = new(55,y)` in the first case is an **inner constructor**. Inner because it lives inside of the type definition. Constructors always exist, i.e. even if you comment out these lines you can still do `Point{Int64}(3,2)`. So what you are actually doing is overriding the default constructor by explicitly telling Julia what to do for the particular case `G<:Integer`, namely to always set `x` to `55`. The `new(55,y)` then actually creates an `Point{G}` object with `x=55` and `y=y`. (Note that we would have a loop if you would write `Point{G}(x,y) where {G<:Integer} = Point{G}(55,y)`, so something like `new()` is indeed necessary.) Technically, you should use `new{G}(55,y)` to create the `Point{G}` object but Julia is clever enough to automatically take the `G` from the constructor on the lhs. This will be an issue in case 2.

The output of

```
julia> println(methods(Point)) # Interesting!!!
# 1 method for generic function "(::Type)":
(::Type{T})(arg) where T in Base at sysimg.jl:77
```

tells you that there are constructors that you can call by just taking the type name (including type parameters) as function name, for example `Point{Float64}(1.2, 3.4)`. I don't know why Julia doesn't list the different constructors explicitly.

```
# Are these methods? Are they 'constructors'?
Point(x::T, y::T) where {T<:Integer} = Point{T}(x,y)
Point(x::T, y::T) where {T<:AbstractFloat} = Point{T}(x,y)
println(methods(Point))
```

These are methods. One indication for this is that you could name them differently: `create_a_point(x::T, y::T) where {T<:Integer} = Point{T}(x,y)`. You couldn't do this for (inner) constructors. However, sometimes they are called 'constructor methods'.

**Second case**

You must specify the type parameter explicitly: `new{T}(55,y)`. Different to case 1 there is no type parameter given on the lhs that Julia could use automatically.

Maybe someone with more technical knowledge of Julia can give an more precise answer. But until then, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you that's very helpful. Yes I read that section of the documentation but your answer has helped to clear things up lots!